# Flutter with Firebase-Firestore (listview)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I try to show a collection with the listview.builder in my flutter app, but I always encountered an error and I really don't know how to make it works.

Here is my code :

```
class _MessagesPageState extends State<MessagesPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    
    
    super.initState();
  }

  _MessagesPageState();
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: null,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>( // inside the <> you enter the type of your stream
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('title'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
cloud_firestore: 2.5.2
firebase_core: ^1.23.0
```

Comment: "I always encountered an error" What is the error you get? Please edit your question to include the exact message, and the stack trace.

Comment: My code always goes to 

```if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }```

But i can't know why.

Comment: Either print the error in console or display the error in text widget using `spanshot.error`.

Comment: it works! I was missing some requirements in my firebase "rules".

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should Initialize Firebase here:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

After doing the above, I don't know if this will work but try something like this:

```
class _MessagesPageState extends State<MessagesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: null,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>( // inside the <> you enter the type of your stream
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  snapshot.data.docs[index].get('title'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```